# CountVectorizer running out of memory when converting from sparse to dense

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, out-of-memory, text-classification

I'm trying to run this code to calculate the relative frequency of each word in a bunch of documents (a lot, more than 40000), i cannot reduce the vocabulary size and it throws out of memory error when runnign on Colab with 12 gb RAM.
How can i refactor the code so that i don't have to call X.toarray() converting from sparse to dense and throws an out of memory error (120000 word * 40000 documents).

```
vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=list(word_to_index.keys()), tokenizer=lambda x: x.split())
X = vect.fit_transform(docs)
X_arr = X.toarray()
rel_freq = np.sum(X_arr, axis=0) / len(docs)
names = vect.get_feature_names()
```

If you are wondering why i need to do this is because i'm implementing ConWea code:
https://github.com/dheeraj7596/ConWea with a bigger amount of data than the author.
Thank you very much to everyone.

Comment: Try params `max_df` and/or `min_df`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the frequency, you can sum up using the [sum method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sum.html) for sparse matrix:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

corpus = ['This is the first document.','This is the second second document.',
'And the third one.','Is this the first document?']

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

X.sum(axis=0)/len(corpus)
matrix([[0.25, 0.75, 0.5 , 0.75, 0.25, 0.5 , 1.  , 0.25, 0.75]])

X.toarray().sum(axis=0)/ len(corpus)
array([0.25, 0.75, 0.5 , 0.75, 0.25, 0.5 , 1.  , 0.25, 0.75])
```

Comment: This is great, works perfectly I should tell also to the paper author